# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bmb0gfx2\jws\

Tags: python

i am trying using firebase to deploy my django
so i install pyrebase
but it happens

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bmb0gfx2\jws\setup.py", line 17, in <module>
    long_description=read('README.md'),
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bmb0gfx2\jws\setup.py", line 5, in read
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp950' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 500: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bmb0gfx2\jws\

pip version 18.1
python version 3.71
and i install setuptools and ezsetup
but it's not work
still report python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

i move to the location temp and i can't find  pip-install-bmb0gfx2\jws
what's that?
it's a empty data.

Comment: I don't think that temporary location is the source of the problem. After the script ends it might be deleted so you find it empty when you look at it. Maybe the problem is that README.md has some special character, I assume it could be Chinese, and it is not supported by the default encoding of the environment where you are running the script.

Comment: no i checked the README.md not find chinese i used english to execute it over all